# Jackson serialize Object to JSON to base64 (without endless loop)

Tags: java, json, jackson, base64, jackson-databind

Is there a simple way to serialize an object using Jackson to base64 encoded JSON? (object -> JSON -> base64)

I tried using a custom `StdSerializer`, but this (of course) results in a endless loop:

```java
class MySerializer extends StdSerializer<Foo> {
  public void serialize(Foo value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    JsonGenerator newGen = gen.getCodec().getFactory().createGenerator(stringWriter);
    gen.getCodec().getFactory().getCodec().writeValue(newGen, value);
    String json = stringWriter.toString();
    String base64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(json.getBytes()));
    gen.writeString(base64);
  }
}
```

A workaround is to copy all fields to another class and use that class for the intermediate representation:

```java
class TmpFoo {
  public String field1;
  public int field2;
  // ...
}

class MySerializer extends StdSerializer<Foo> {
  public void serialize(Foo value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) {
    TmpFoo tmp = new TmpFoo();
    tmp.field1 = value.field1;
    tmp.field2 = value.field2;
    // etc.

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    JsonGenerator newGen = gen.getCodec().getFactory().createGenerator(stringWriter);
    gen.getCodec().getFactory().getCodec().writeValue(newGen, tmp); // here "tmp" instead of "value"
    String json = stringWriter.toString();
    String base64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(json.getBytes()));
    gen.writeString(base64);
  }
}
```

Creating a `new ObjectMapper` is not desired, because I need all registered modules and serializers of the default ObjectMapper.

I was hoping for some easier way of achieving this.

---

### EDIT: Example

Step 1: Java Object

```java
class Foo {
  String field1 = "foo";
  int field2 = 42;
}
```

Step 2: JSON

```
{"field1":"foo","field2":42}
```

Step 3: Base64

```
eyJmaWVsZDEiOiJmb28iLCJmaWVsZDIiOjQyfQ==
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this site](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-call-default-serializer-from-custom-serializer), there is a workaround to avoid this recursion problem:

> When we define a custom serializer, Jackson internally overrides the
>   original BeanSerializer instance [...] our SerializerProvider finds
>   the customized serializer every time, instead of the default one, and
>   this causes an infinite loop.
>
> A possible workaround is using BeanSerializerModifier to store the
>   default serializer for the type Folder before Jackson internally
>   overrides it.

If I understood the workaround correctly, your `Serializer` should look like this:

```java
class FooSerializer extends StdSerializer<Foo> {

    private final JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer;

    public FooSerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer) {
        super(Foo.class);
        this.defaultSerializer = defaultSerializer;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Foo value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        JsonGenerator tempGen = provider.getGenerator().getCodec().getFactory().createGenerator(stringWriter);
        defaultSerializer.serialize(value, tempGen, provider);

        tempGen.flush();

        String json = stringWriter.toString();
        String base64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(json.getBytes()));
        gen.writeString(base64);
    }
}
```

In addition to the serializer, a modifier is needed:

```java
public class FooBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(
      SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {

        if (beanDesc.getBeanClass().equals(Foo.class)) {
            return new FooSerializer((JsonSerializer<Object>) serializer);
        }
        return serializer;
    }
}
```

Example module:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.setSerializerModifier(new FooBeanSerializerModifier());

mapper.registerModule(module);
```

**EDIT:**

I've added `flush()` to flush the `JsonGenerator tempGen`.
Also, I've created a minimal test enviroment with JUnit, which verifies your Example with `Foo`: The github repo can be found [here](https://github.com/PSandro/JacksonBase64Serializer).

---

**EDIT: Alternative 2**

Another (simple) option is using a wrapper class with generics:

```java
public class Base64Wrapper<T> {

    private final T wrapped;

    private Base64Wrapper(T wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public T getWrapped() {
        return this.wrapped;
    }

    public static <T> Base64Wrapper<T> of(T wrapped) {
        return new Base64Wrapper<>(wrapped);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Base64WrapperSerializer extends StdSerializer<Base64Wrapper> {


    public Base64WrapperSerializer() {
        super(Base64Wrapper.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Base64Wrapper value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        JsonGenerator tempGen = provider.getGenerator().getCodec().getFactory().createGenerator(stringWriter);
        provider.defaultSerializeValue(value.getWrapped(), tempGen);
        tempGen.flush();

        String json = stringWriter.toString();
        String base64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(json.getBytes()));
        gen.writeString(base64);
    }
}
```

An example usecase would be:

```java
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(new Base64WrapperSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

final Foo foo = new Foo();
final Base64Wrapper<Foo> base64Wrapper = Base64Wrapper.of(foo);
final String base64Json = mapper.writeValueAsString(base64Wrapper);
```

This example can be found in [this GitHub](https://github.com/PSandro/JacksonBase64Serializer/tree/wrapper) (branch: wrapper) repo, verifing you BASE64 String from your foo example with JUnit testing.

Comment: Looked promising, but somehow doesn't work. BeanSerializerModifier and StdSerializer are called correctly, but `stringWriter.toString()` results in an empty string. When writing to `gen` instead of `tempGen` the data object looks fine, but then of course base64 encoding isn't possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer: `flush()` was missing for `tempGen`. You can have a look at the github repo, I've linked. There, the result gets verified in a test. Hope, it works now :)

Comment: @BenjaminM I've again updated my answer. There's a second alternative to get the base64 encoded json of an Object, by wrapping it up in `Base64Wrapper` from my example above.  `Base64Wrapper` has its custom serializer `Base64WrapperSerializer` which gets the wrapped Object default-serialized and encodes it as base64. This method is probably better if you have a custom serializer for `Foo` and want to choose between it beeing json-serialized and then base64 encoded or just json-serialized without base64.

Comment: Thanks for your passion `:)` ! I've search and tried a few more things, and now I'm pretty sure, that there's no "easy" way to achieve this simple task. The base64 wrapper looks pretty nice, but sadly I can't use it, because I can't modify the source object. Nevertheless thumbs up. You earned that bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating new object you may convert existing one into map. Like in the example below

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

public class FooSerializer extends StdSerializer<Foo> {

    public FooSerializer() {
        super(Foo.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Foo foo, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonGenerator.getCodec();
            var map = toMap(foo); // if you need class info for deserialization than use toMapWithClassInfo
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
            jsonGenerator.writeString(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(json.getBytes(UTF_8)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> toMap(Object o) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        Field[] declaredFields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : declaredFields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            result.put(field.getName(), field.get(o));
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static Map<String, Object> toMapWithClassInfo(Object obj) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(obj.getClass());
        for (PropertyDescriptor pd : info.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            Method reader = pd.getReadMethod();
            if (reader != null)
                result.put(pd.getName(), reader.invoke(obj));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm providing 2 ways of converting into map: with and without class info. Choose the one, applicable to your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Using a Map as intermediate representation seems okay, too. But that still feels cumbersome and isn't much different or easier than using a second class with the same properties.

Answer (score 0):

To serialize object jackson search `@JsonValue` method. You can add `encodedJsonString` method annotated by `@JsonValue` in `Foo` class.

Try with this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String field1;
    public int field2;

    @JsonValue
    public String toEncodedJsonString() {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            new ObjectOutputStream(baos).writeObject(this);
            return org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(baos.toByteArray());
        }catch (Exception ex){

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want a serialized form of binary Java object representation. I want a base64 encoded JSON string within a JSON document. I'll add an example to the question